# Simple mysql event not running

Tags: php, mysql

I have an event in my mysql database called "updategold", what it should do is increase a table value by 5 every second. It doesn't work, though. No error messages, everything looks ok but it is just not running. Here's how it is set up:

- Event name: Updategold
- Stats: Enabled
- Event type: Recurring
- Execute every: 1, second
- Start: I set it to a couple of mins in the future
- End: empty
- Definition (supposed to run this every second):

  ```
  update stats.gold set stats.gold = stats.gold + 5
  where stats.id = users.id
  ```
- Definer: root@localhost

Any ideas?

EDIT

Entire process

```
DROP EVENT `updategold`; CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` EVENT `updategold` ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1    SECOND STARTS '2014-10-19 11:37:00.000000' ON COMPLETION NOT PRESERVE ENABLE DO update stats set stats.gold = stats.gold + 5 where stats.id = users.id
```

Comment: It would help to have the actual code.

Comment: @maythesource.com Can't remember what I put into the console, wil emulate it and try again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your syntax is wrong in update stats.**gold**, you should only give the `table_name`

```
 update stats.gold set stats.gold = stats.gold + 5 
     where stats.id = users.id
```

should be:

```
 UPDATE stats SET stats.gold = stats.gold + 5 
     INNER JOIN users 
         ON stats.id = users.id
```

and added a `JOIN` to select the users to be updated from the users table.

Comment: I actually noticed that shortly afterwards lol Still doesn't seem to be working though EDIT - I need the where

Comment: Already updated the question since you check for `users.id` you'll either have to join the two tables or select the user, or update all rows in the stats which sounds reasonable if i am guessing your intents correctly

Comment: Yes since i guess you only need the `users` who have `stats`. Try it without `where` and no `join` to make sure it is working fine, and then complete the rest of your logic.

Comment: AWESOME it works! thanks :) want to put the inner join part in your answer as that is what fixed it

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's your syntax. Have you done it like this?

```
UPDATE table_name
SET column1=value1,column2=value2,...
WHERE some_column=some_value;
```

Comment: I want to increase the value, in this case I want the value in column1 to increase, not just be set